# Cannot type backquote or backtick in xterm

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, xterm, input, special-characters

Ubuntu 10.10, XTerm(261), Keyboard layout = Canadian

Somehow, the backquote (backtick = `) character can't be input does not get entered in XTerm. I type it and nothing happens. The cursor does not move forward.

I know it works because I can input it in Terminal (gnome-terminal). The only strange thing is that I have to type the key twice for it to appear.

Just to test it, I tried typing it in other applications, and the same thing happens. Have to type it twice in FF, gedit, etc. One more strange thing, I could not input it into this textbox in which I am typing this message. But I can input it in the URL bar, search bar, etc.

Someone please help me solve this mystery. I like to use XTerm and I need the backquotes.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the keybindings. Found a [post](http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1203002&tstart=0&messageID=6327198#6327198) for Terminal on Mac OS X. It was a specific plugin in that case.

Comment: termcap? terminfo? maybe that has something to do with it ... something is intercepting that backtick ... all other special characters can be input without problem.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility to disable dead keys might be to change your keyboard layout in system preferences to something that doesn't use them (like US).

You will notice, by the way, that in addition to pressing backtick twice to get one backtick character, you can press it once then press "e" to get a "è" (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE).

Comment: What I don't understand is why I can't enter it into XTerm and some select places (like this textbox). Note that I can enter the e with grave è in this textbox. But not the backtick itself. I can type the accented é into XTerm as it is a key on the keyboard. I don't want to change the keyboard layout. There has to be a reason and some solution.